How to create an interactive circular radial tree / dendrogram similar to the one shown in my post using Python?
I am trying to figure out how to create a radial tree / hub and spoke graph similar to the one shown below using Python (which comes from the sample Flourish.studio radial tree).  I've tried using Plotly but with no success.
It would be especially great if it also was exportable in a file type that I could embed into a PowerPoint presentation.
It would be even better if the graphic also had a dropdown menu in the upper left (like is shown in the image below), where I could pick a particular primary spoke from the dropdown menu (e.g., South Asia), and then the graphic would show only the data on the south Asian tree.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Sample data:

